# unable to execute sql query on over

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to execute this query but its showing error

```
select 
    order_id, 
    product_id 
from (select 
        order_id, 
        product_id, 
        count(*) over(partition by order_id, product_id) as dc  
      from order_items
      ) 
where dc > 1  ;
```

error  i am getting is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by order_id, product_id) as dc  from order_items) where dc > 1' at line 1

Comment: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?32,225340,225340#msg-225340

Comment: any solution for my above query? Please help me , now i am in miserable condition w.r.t this query

Comment: There are workarounds at the link I posted.

Comment: @Barmar I read it but its so complicated for me to understand. If know then please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL still doesn't support windowing functions. Therefore `OVER` clause won't work in MySQL.

You can emulate it either with a subquery or by using user (session) variables.

One way to select **actual** rows from `order_items` where the same product_id occurs more than once per order

```
select i.*, 
       (
         select count(*) 
           from order_items
          where order_id = i.order_id 
            and product_id = i.product_id
       ) as dc  
  from order_items i
having dc > 1
```

or with join

```
select i.*, dc
  from
(
  select order_id, product_id, count(*) dc
    from order_items
   group by order_id, product_id
  having dc > 1
) q join order_items i
    on q.order_id = i.order_id
   and q.product_id = i.product_id;
```

If on the the other hand you need **only** order_id and product_id and a count total for such rows

```
select order_id, product_id, count(*) dc
  from order_items
 group by order_id, product_id
having dc > 1;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d421a/7)** demo

Comment: @DhruvJoshi Poor answer

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
        order_id, 
        product_id
              from order_items
        group by order_id, product_id
       having count(*)>1
```